# User "system:anonymous" cannot create resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying to run Spark on EKS. Created an EKS cluster, added nodes and then trying to submit a Spark job from an EC2 instance.

Ran following commands for access:

```
kubectl create serviceaccount spark
kubectl create clusterrolebinding spark-role --clusterrole=admin --serviceaccount=default:spark --namespace=default
```

spark-submit command used:

```
bin/spark-submit \
--master k8s://https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name spark-pi \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
--conf spark.app.name=spark-pi \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark  \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=k8sspark:latest \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.caCertFile=ca.pem \
local:////usr/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.3.jar 100000
```

It returns:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>   Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
>   19/06/06 16:03:50 WARN WatchConnectionManager: Executor didn't terminate in time after shutdown in close(), killing it in: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatchConnectionManager@5b43fbf6
>   Exception in thread "main" io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: POST at: https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods. Message: pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default". Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=403, details=StatusDetails(causes=[], group=null, kind=pods, name=null, retryAfterSeconds=null, uid=null, additionalProperties={}), kind=Status, message=pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default", metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=Forbidden, status=Failure, additionalProperties={}).
>           at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.requestFailure(OperationSupport.java:478)
>           at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.assertResponseCode(OperationSupport.java:417)
>           at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:381)
>           at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:344)
>           at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleCreate(OperationSupport.java:227)
>           at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleCreate(BaseOperation.java:787)
>           at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.create(BaseOperation.java:357)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.Client$$anonfun$run$2.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:141)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.Client$$anonfun$run$2.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:140)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2543)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.Client.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:140)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication$$anonfun$run$5.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:250)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication$$anonfun$run$5.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:241)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2543)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:241)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.start(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:204)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>   19/06/06 16:03:50 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
>   19/06/06 16:03:50 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-0060fe01-33eb-4cb4-b96b-d5be687016bc

Tried creating different clusterrole with admin privilege. But it did not work.

Any idea how to fix this one?

Comment: how did you create the pod? did you attach the service account to it? it seems like your pod is not getting assigned the service account you created.

Comment: For me it's more like authentication issue, as your connection to k8s cluster turns to `system:anonymous`, may suggest to add also `--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthToken` property and provide appropriate token.

Comment: does sudo ./bin/spark-submit work for you ?

Comment: Hi, did you find the issue? I am also stuck at same point.

Comment: @NumeroUno   did you solve the issue :) ?